# Cygwin: how can I make cygwin recognize the programs that I installed in Window?

Tags: git, cygwin

I just started using cygwin in Window 7. I now that I can install for example say git through the cygwin setup file by downloading the package. However, I am curious that suppose I download a git exe file from internet and installed it into Window 7, how can I make cygwin recognize git in this situation and allow me to use git on command line?

In fact how can I make cygwin recognize the programs that I downloaded from the internet (not from the cygwin setup.exe) and installed into my Window 7  ?

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I make cygwin recognize the programs that I downloaded from the internet (not from the cygwin setup.exe) and installed into my Window 7 ?

You don't: the [Git for Windows msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/) (which includes a `git.exe`), or any other exe are meant to be executed by the OS Windows.

The git you can install in Cygwin is one meant to be executed in a Linux-like bash session.

Although it is possible to launch Windows applications from the Cygwin environment, git.exe itself expect a Windows environment (with `%HOME%` environment variable, not `$HOME`).